# meson linker error when adding dependency

Tags: c++, macos, meson-build

I am trying to switch to meson and evaluate. I setup a small project and created this meson.build file

```
project('utils', 'cpp')
json_dep = dependency('jsoncpp')
boost_dep = dependency('boost', modules : [ 'filesystem' ])
occ_dep = dependency('OpenCASCADE', method: 'cmake')

utils_deps = [ occ_dep, json_dep, boost_dep ]
utils_lib = library('utils', dependencies: utils_deps)
```

If I use `utils_deps = [ json_dep, boost_dep ]` then the compilation works. However adding `occ_dep` to the list and compiling produces the following error

```
FAILED: src/libs/utils/libutils.dylib
c++  -o src/libs/utils/libutils.dylib  -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,
-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-undefined,error -shared -install_name 
@rpath/libutils.dylib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/lib 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libTKernel.7.6.2.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/tbb/lib/libtbb.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/opt/tbb/lib/libtbbmalloc.dylib /opt/homebrew/lib/libTKMath.7.6.2.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libTKG2d.7.6.2.dylib /opt/homebrew/lib/libTKG3d.7.6.2.dylib 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
  MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
  MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libTKService.7.6.2.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/opt/freeimage/lib/libfreeimage.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.dylib 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
  MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework 
/opt/homebrew/lib/libTKQADraw.7.6.2.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/lib/libjsoncpp.dylib 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.78.0_1/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib

ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am working on a Macbook Pro M1 cheap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems that in the linking file it search a file instead of Library

```
/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework
```

your dependency against OpenCascade uses cmake method, try to specify  also the lib needed using modules method

```
occ_dep = dependency('OpenCASCADE', method: 'cmake', modules : ['openCascade lib ......'])
```

see also https://mesonbuild.com/Dependencies.html